# Quote equality test in batch

Tags: batch-file, escaping, quote

How can I test my string as if it is a quote (") or not.
The default escape character is '^', isn't it?
So I tried the following but with no success yet:

```
if  "!first_char!" == "^"" (...)
```

I tried double quote, too:

```
if  "!first_char!" == """" (...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the right part of the comparison, but with the left part. As first_char contains a quote, then the left operand of the comparison does not make sense. So you have to escape with `^` the variable that holds the `"`.

try something like this...

```
if .^!first_char!.==.^". (@echo ^!first_char! YES) else (@echo ^!first_char! NO)
```

Comment: Nice explanation, but completly wrong :-) for delayed expansion, as the delayed expansions doesn't have any special effects, independent of the content

Comment: Yes, but the caret before the exclamation mark is useless, it works also with `.!first_char!.` instead of `.^!first_char!.`, as the caret is removed before the expansion is executed

Comment: @PA: Your code works, only the explanation is incorrect. And this works too `if !first_char!==^" (@echo !first_char! YES) else (@echo !first_char! NO)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only on the right part of the comparision.
The delayed expansion on the left side is always safe.
So you could simply use also a delayed expansion on the right side, like

```
set singleQuote="
if  "!first_char!" == "!singleQuote!" (...)
```

Or alternativly you could escape all quotes.

```
if  "!first_char!" == ^"^"^" (...)
```